# Sitecore Custom MVC Form with file upload, file always null

Tags: mvc, mvc-forms

I have the following model

```cs
public class VacancyDetailModel
{
    public HttpPostedFileBase Resume {get;set; }
}
```

This is my form.

```html
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
  <input type="file" name="Resume" />
  <input type="hidden" name="fhController" value="VacanciesController" />
  <input type="hidden" name="fhAction" value="VacancyDetail" />
  <button id="btn-save" class="btn btn-highlight" type="submit">Solliciteer direct empty form</button>
}
```

This is my controller

```cs
[HttpPost]     
//[ValidateFormHandler]       
public ActionResult VacancyDetail(VacancyDetailModel formModel)
{
    return this.View(model);
}
```

When I place a watch on my model, the Resume field is always `null`.

Comment: Can you share the controller code as well, please. In the VacanciesController where you encounter NULL?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to define your form properly for file uploads to work. The most important part is to set `enctype` to `multipart/form-data`. Normally, you should use the standard `Html.BeginForm` helper:

```razor
@using (Html.BeginForm("VacancyDetail", "VacanciesController", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
  <input type="file" name="Resume" />
  <button id="btn-save" class="btn btn-highlight" type="submit">Solliciteer direct empty form</button>
}
```

If you, for some reason, can't use a fully parameterized `Html.BeginForm`, use raw HTML instead:

```html
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="file" name="Resume" />
  <input type="hidden" name="fhController" value="VacanciesController" />
  <input type="hidden" name="fhAction" value="VacancyDetail" />
  <button id="btn-save" class="btn btn-highlight" type="submit">Solliciteer direct empty form</button>
</form>
```

You can find more examples on the [**Haacked blog**](http://haacked.com/archive/2010/07/16/uploading-files-with-aspnetmvc.aspx/).

Comment: I can't use Html.BeginForm("VacancyDetail", "VacanciesController" 
in Sitecore according to my other question I asked here. So I need a empty beginform()

Comment: @DannyH I have edited my answer according to your request.

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify an `enctype` of **multipart/form-data** if your form uses file input types.

You can either do this manually:

```html
<form action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
```

Or by using the HtmlHelper, but you would need to use the particular overload that allows you to specify HTML attributes:

```razor
@using (Html.BeginForm("Action", "Controller", FormMethod.Post, new {enctype = "multipart/form-data" })) {
```

Comment: I can't use Html.BeginForm("VacancyDetail", "VacanciesController" 
in SiteCore according to my other question I asked here. So I need a empty beginform()

Comment: You can use the manual form entry to achieve the same as BeginForm(), alternatively you could also look at the source for BeginForm so that you can create your own extension that allows you to specify the HTML attributes but no controller / action.